# androidでリナックスターミナルを使いたいです

Tags: android, linux

androidで仮想やエミュレーターではなくアンドロイドの中のリナックスでターミナルを使いたいです
用途はドライバのインストールです

Comment: jailbreak (脱獄) しなきゃできないはず

Comment: root化できました